# Using will_paginate on a collection of records changes the paginated results count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, will-paginate

We have models `Subscription` and `SubscriptionCart`. A `Subscription` `has_many` `SubscriptionCart`.

We have and use a relation between the two models to get a `Subscription`'s oldest cart where the `plan_id` changed to the current `Subscription` `plan_id` (in other words, the first cart that defined the current `Subscription` plan)

The `Subscription` relation goes as follows:

```
has_one     :first_version_with_current_plan, -> {
    joins(:subscription)
      .where(subscription_carts: { status: "processed" })
      .where("subscription_carts.plan_id = subscriptions.plan_id")
      .order("subscription_carts.authorized_at ASC")
  }, class_name: "SubscriptionCart", inverse_of: :subscription
```

The above relation will return a `Subscription` (parent) with the first cart (child) where the `plan_id` changed to whatever the `Subscription` `plan_id` is.

We are using that relation in an index view where we are using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) to display the results.

controller:

```
  def index
    @subscriptions = current_account.subscriptions
      .includes(:first_version_with_current_plan)
      .order("subscription_carts.authorized_at ASC") # relation attribute
      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
      
  end
```

**The issue** we are having is that before the `.paginate` method `@subscriptions.count` will return 50 but applying `.paginate` to the collection renders less than 10 total results in the view.

I'm suspecting `will_paginate` makes a second query behind the scenes that is breaking the results count, but I'm not sure as I haven't found much online.

Is there any explanation to this or any known workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination should change the count - the whole point is to limit the amount of data fetch from the database by applying limits and offsets. When paginating the count is always equal to or smaller than the `per_page` setting - after all you're only fetching that many rows from the table.

If you want a count of the total number of records you need to either create a separate count query on the scope without pagination:

```
def index
  scope = current_account.subscriptions
    .includes(:first_version_with_current_plan)
    .order("subscription_carts.authorized_at ASC")
  @count = scope.count
  @subscriptions = scope.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end
```

If you want a count of the total number of records you need to either create a separate count query on the scope without pagination or use counter caches on your model.

Comment: I don't think I explained myself correctly. I understand that upon using `will_paginate` the `count` will return as many records as the `per_page` param since that is what "fits" in the page. The issue I'm having is that the results before and after the pagination are not the same. If `@subscriptions` has a total size of 50 records, using `.paginate` on that collection changes the total amount of records to 10 or less. So 50 records become less than 10, as if the query was completely different.

Comment: In other words, I run the same query on console and get 50 results, but applying `.paginate` displays 10 out of 10 records instead of having 3 pages with 20, 20 and 10 results. That is why I think a second query is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: If you have 50 records and a page limit of 20 and are on page 3 you have OFFSET 40 LIMIT 20 so its completely logical that you get a count of 10. It does not create 3 different queries as that would be extremely ineffective.

Comment: I realized the question in the title is a bit misleading. It is not just the `count` that is wrong. It's the whole data set returned after applying `.paginate` on the collection. If the scope returns 50 records on console, I'd expect that applying pagination on it results in the same records divided in as many pages as needed depending on the `per_page` param. But what I'm getting is a completely different data set of records compared to what I get on console, the most apparent thing being that the total amount of paginated results are less than the total I get on console.

Comment: Write a model test that replicates what you expect to be getting. But I still just think you have got it backwards. Pagination doesn't actually give you the results split into pages - it just gives you *that* page based on a precalculated offset. To get other pages you perform more queries.

Comment: Thanks. I certainly did not know about the OFFSET. Still, shouldn't the first page of results have the same records as the first records in the collection I get without using the same scope but no pagination?

Dataset ids comparisson:

Pagination:

`[40, 41, 129, 71, 75, 95, 101, 120, 122, 123, 106]`

No pagination: 

`[40, 41, 129, 71, 75, 95, 101, 120, 122, 123, 106, 126, 125, 124, 128, 118, 38, 48, 67, 86, 88, 96, 105, 107, 66, 68, 69, 81, 82, 83, 85, 104, 99, 100, 87, 94, 103, 108, 110, 116, 111, 114, 113, 115, 117, 119, 80, 121, 127]`